# How to Connect sql server with C#?

Tags: c#, database, connection-string

I am facing problem in connectivity to my database does anyone know what causes this problem?

Thanks

code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string connetionString = null;

    SqlConnection cnn;

    connetionString = "Data Source=UMAIR;Initial Catalog=Air.dbo;User ID=;Password=";
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
        cnn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
    }
}
```

it always shows me that "Can not open connection error! "

Comment: are you providing correct user name and passowrd to connect?

Comment: please check your connection details[Db name,username and password] are correct?

Comment: What is the actual exception that is being thrown?

Comment: There are hundreds if not thousands of examples online on how to connect to a SQL Server. I suggest checking http://www.connectionstrings.com/ and perhaps do some research before we continue this question.

Comment: there is no user name password...

Comment: Did you specify the user id and passowrd in the code while executing?

Comment: Is the database name `Air.dbo` correct ?

Comment: Are you using Windows authentication mode?

Comment: yes i am using Windows authentication Mode

Comment: @UmairJaved - Is the database is on the same computer as the application?

Comment: ya datbase is on the same application

Comment: `Exception ex` is full of useful information, that you aren't looking at.

Answer (score 3):

I really doubt that you have a database named

```
Air.dbo
```

Probably, if you use Sql Authentication, your connection string should be

```
Data Source=UMAIR;Initial Catalog=Air;User ID=yourusername;Password=yourpassword";
```

Instead, if you use windows authentication (meaning your login name and password are used to connect to the database) then your connection string should change to

```
Data Source=UMAIR;Initial Catalog=Air;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

Also you should be sure that your SqlServer is installed on the server named UMAIR without an instance name.

Please review the numerous form of connection string valid for SqlServer at this [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: ya i have tried this also but all in vain... and second thing is i am using windows authentication mode.. there is no username and password

Comment: @UmairJaved - Your connection string is incorrect.  There actually is a username and password so sending a null string for both would attempt to do something else entirely.  You have not tried the second connection string Steve suggested, before you claim it does not work, you might want to try it.

Comment: What is the name of your database (Initial Catalog=?) and what is the name of your machine where the Sql Server software has been installed? Is this machine your own machine or a machine in your lan environment? All these question affects the connection string to be build.

Comment: The second option I suppose right?

Comment: yes steve its right .. thanks

Comment: @UmairJaved Well,, since you are new on StackOverflow, if an answer that was provided seems to be the answer you were looking for then you should mark that answer as correct (little green v thingy on under the votes of the answer). That way the person answering gets the recognition and for future references (people with same problem) can identify the answer quicker.

Comment: I see you are new here on SO, please take your time to review the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). And thanks @SynerCoder, I was writing the same thing. However the OP is a new user and he will need to wait before accepting the answer.

Comment: The wait time (as far as I know) is 15minutes, those have passed already. Or is the limit higher for new users?

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionString does not look right? Are you using SQL server authentication or windows authenticaiton? If SQL authenction, you need to pass correct username and password in connectionstring. If windows authentication, remove User Id and password, set Integrated security to true.

Also Do you have access to machine with name UMAIR?

Comment: can you please write the correct string..

Comment: @UmairJaved - There are examples over at http://www.connectionstrings.com/